# How to edit "path" and "ConfigurationLocation" of a VM in Hyper-V 2012 R2

Tags: powershell, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I need to make some changes to a Hyper-V storage and I need to modify certain settings of each VM on the host.

The values I need to change are:

- ConfigurationLocation
- SnapshotFileLocation
- SmartPagingFilePath
- Path

I can change the 2nd and the 3rd with this command:

```
set-vm -VMName $vm -SmartPagingFilePath $newVMPath -SnapshotFileLocation $newVMPath
```

However, there are no apparent switches for the "path" and "configurationlocation" parameters. How do I set them with Powershell?

Comment: Have the files already been moved?  The `Move-VM` commandlet lets you relocate these files.

Comment: No the files will not need to move. Hyper-V hosts were accessing them with an SOFS share before, such as \\sofsshare\hyper-v\VMX\, which is the same path as c:\ClusterSharedVolume\share\hyper-v\VMX. If only I could change the path/configurationlocation, they would probably work well. (I will of course test this before production)

Answer (score 1):

ConfigurationLocation is a read-only property, it just indicates the current file location. AFAIK there's no way to change ConfigurationLocation and Path properties without actually moving the VM.

You can change the default Hyper-V Virtual Machines folder though, but this is not your case..